# Is it possible to check the size of video while recording? Note:( i am not using native camera application.)

Tags: android, android-camera

I have to add a feature in an app in which i want to record video and to stop the recording when the file size exceeds to certain limit.Is that possible? I know that file size can be checked after saving. But I want to know whether this can be done on run time.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `setMaxFileSize()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setMaxFileSize(long)) when configuring `MediaRecorder` to record your video.